# check which button the user clicked at the prompt from onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript

How can i find out whether a user pressed the left button (confirm) or the right button (cancel) at the box which is shown if the event `onbeforeunload` fires?

```js
function ask()
{
  var ret = confirm("sure?");  //ERROR: Blocked confirm('sure?') during beforeunload.

  if (ret) console.log("User pressed confirm button");

  return "are you sure?";
}
```

```html
<body onbeforeunload="return ask()">
    <h1>onbeforeunload Test</h1>
    <a href="http://www.google.de">Google</a>
</body>
```

Comment: If page refreshes right button clicked else left button clicked;

Answer (score 1):

For safety purposes this is not possible anymore. Therefore you cannot do anything else than return some text and if user refuses to refresh, page will not be refreshed and in other case page will be refreshed.

Comment: I don't understand the risk to be honest.

Comment: There are many pages that "spam" you and wrong click can cause lots of trouble. Therefore risk is prevented because leaving the page shouldn't be restricted in that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify browser back button event using window.event.clientX and window.event.clientY property as follow:

```
if(window.event.clientX < 40 && window.event.clientY < 0)
{
    alert("Browser back button is clicked…");
}
else
{
    alert("Browser refresh button is clicked…");
}
```

For reference follow the below link :-

http://www.webdevelopmenthelp.net/2013/12/browser-back-button-click-event.html

Comment: This does not show me whether the user pressed the confirm or cancel button. But thx.